# Perl crawler is throwing "XPath failure" error even though the XPath is available

Tags: perl, xpath, web-crawler

My Perl crawler is throwing "XPath failure" error even though the xpath is available. Sometimes i get empty crawl content even though the content is there, but if I run the script again I am get the proper crawl content. If I process 100 URLs then I get this xpath failure error for 3 to 5 URLs. I increased the timeout to 660 seconds but the error remained. When I run the script again everything works fine.

Here is the crawler section of my code; I am reading the input (`url`, `xpath`) from a db.

```
use LWP::Simple;
use File::Compare;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $url    = $results->{url};
my $xpath  = $results->{xpath};
my $region = $results->{region};

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => "Mozilla/30.0" );
$ua->timeout(660);
$ua->env_proxy;

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => "$url" );
my $res = $ua->request($req);
delete $ENV{HTTP_PROXY};
my $error = $res->status_line;

if ( $res->is_success )    #if status is 200
{
    $htmlcreation = "$competitor.html";
    my $xp = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $res->decoded_content );

    if ( $xp->findnodes_as_string($xpath) ) {

        my $raw_html           = $xp->findnodes_as_string($xpath);
        my $hs                 = HTML::Strip->new();
        my $clean_text_content = decode_utf8( $hs->parse( encode_utf8($raw_html) ) );
        $hs->eof;

        foreach ($competitor) {
            open HTML_crawl, '>:encoding(cp1252)', "/var/www/auto-eu/folder_history/crawl_for_$date/$htmlcreation";
            my $fileper = "/var/www/auto-eu/folder_history/crawl_for_$date/$htmlcreation";
            chmod( 0777, $fileper );

            print HTML_crawl $clean_text_content;    #write crawled content with competitor name
            close HTML_crawl;

        }
    } else {
        print "xpath failed";
    }

} else {
    print "service unavailable";
}
```

Comment: From my little experience with crawlers, I'm guessing that the server you're crawling may know that you're crawling it and is intentionally "withholding" content.  Have you tried running these requests through a proxy?  If you can give me some problematic urls, I can try tinkering with it.

Comment: HI Thanks for your feedback.There are couple of old(unused) proxies were configured in that script. When I removed those unused old proxies, everything is working fine now.